# Where do pear packages get installed on the IBM i?

Tags: php, ibm-midrange

I have a V7R1 system with zend zerver and pear seems to work:

```
$ /usr/local/zendsvr6/bin/pear channel-discover pear.phing.info
Adding Channel "pear.phing.info" succeeded
Discovery of channel "pear.phing.info" succeeded
$  /usr/local/zendsvr6/bin/pear install phing/phing
Package "Xdebug" does not have REST info xml available
WARNING: "pear/PEAR_PackageFileManager" is deprecated in favor of "pear/PEAR_PackageFileManager2"
Unknown remote channel: pear.pdepend.org
Unknown remote channel: pear.phpmd.org
Unknown remote channel: pear.phpdoc.org
Did not download optional dependencies: phing/phingdocs, pear/VersionControl_SVN, pear/VersionControl_Git, pecl/Xdebug, pear/PEAR_PackageFileManager, pear/Services_Amazon_S3, pear/HTTP_Request2, channel://pear.pdepend.org/PHP_Depend, channel://pear.phpmd.org/PHP_PMD, channel://pear.phpdoc.org/phpDocumentor, pear/PHP_CodeSniffer, pear/Net_Growl, use --alldeps to download automatically
phing/phing can optionally use package "phing/phingdocs" (version >= 2.12.0)
phing/phing can optionally use package "pear/VersionControl_SVN" (version >= 0.4.0)
phing/phing can optionally use package "pear/VersionControl_Git" (version >= 0.4.3)
phing/phing can optionally use package "pecl/Xdebug" (version >= 2.0.5)
phing/phing can optionally use package "pear/PEAR_PackageFileManager" (version >= 1.5.2)
phing/phing can optionally use package "pear/Services_Amazon_S3" (version >= 0.3.1)
phing/phing can optionally use package "pear/HTTP_Request2" (version >= 2.1.1)
phing/phing can optionally use package "channel://pear.pdepend.org/PHP_Depend" (version >= 0.10.0)
phing/phing can optionally use package "channel://pear.phpmd.org/PHP_PMD" (version >= 1.1.0)
phing/phing can optionally use package "channel://pear.phpdoc.org/phpDocumentor" (version >= 2.0.0b7)
phing/phing can optionally use package "pear/PHP_CodeSniffer" (version >= 1.5.0)
phing/phing can optionally use package "pear/Net_Growl" (version >= 2.6.0)
downloading phing-2.12.0.tgz ...
Starting to download phing-2.12.0.tgz (521,355 bytes)
.........................................................................................................done: 521,355 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.phing.info/phing-2.12.0
```

Where do these get installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently they get installed to `/usr/local/zendsvr6/bin/`and I didn't realize it.